# Which is better grammar: "courteous of" or "courteous to"?

Tags: grammar

I saw this in a document today, and was wondering about which usage is more appropriate.

> Please be courteous of others

vs

> Please be courteous to others

I've seen it both ways. Is one correct, or more appropriate for certain situations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Courteous to others" is correct.  "Courteous of others" is possible, but the former is more common.

Answer (score 1):

For the most part, the two phrasings are indistinguishable, but I believe there are subtly different implications between them.

*Please be courteous of others* is advice to be taken "inwardly"; it is advising its recipient to be *mindful*, to think of the actions that others might take.  In particular, there is a mental component to the prescription; it says, you should *think* of others' desires before doing whatever it is you want to do.

*Please be courteous to others* is advice directed towards "outward" behavior; it advises its recipient to simply *act* courteously, not necessarily think so; it says, you might think as rude as spiteful thoughts as you want, but please observe a modicum of politeness.

Comment: There are no examples of _courteous of_ used like this in either BNC or COCA.  So is it not simply a grammatical error?

Comment: I think it would traditionally be considered an error, yes.

Answer (score -1):

["Courteous to others"](http://www.google.com.ph/search?q=%22courteous%20to%20others%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&client=firefox-a) has 483,000 results on Google vs. ["Courteous of others"](http://www.google.com.ph/search?q=%22courteous%20of%20others%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&client=firefox-a) which only has 85,400 results

Comment: Could you kindly provide some analysis or explanation? Otherwise, merely reporting data does not in any way answer this question.

Comment: @Jimi Oke "Google Similarity Distance" "Kolmogorov complexity" "treat a Google search as a search of the Internet as a corpus"